# android BroadcastReceiver called twice

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver, android-runonuithread

i am working on chat project

what i did here is service with the connection staff and i set a broadcast receiver to get the data from the service

this is the receiver code

```
mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            try {
                final String code = intent.getExtras().get("code").toString();
                final JSONObject Message = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().get("msg").toString());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d("test","test");
                    }
                });
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,new IntentFilter("data"));
```

the problem is when i close the activity the code inside runOnUiThread called more than one time

if i close the activity and open it it called 2 times if i did it again it called 3 times and so on

Comment: You need to unregister the broadcast receiver after your activity is paused.
in onPause() method of your activity.
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver)

Comment: than you @RahulShukla it works after i unregister it

Comment: added the above comment as an answer. Kindly accept the same :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to unregister the broadcast receiver after your activity is paused. in onPause() method of your activity. LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(m‌​MessageReceiver)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way for using `LocalBroadcastManager` is as follows:

```
 public static String REPORTBOOK_BROADCAST = "REPORTBOOK_BROADCAST";

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        recreateLists();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).registerReceiver(reportBookReceiver, new IntentFilter(REPORTBOOK_BROADCAST));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).unregisterReceiver(reportBookReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).unregisterReceiver(reportBookReceiver);
    }
```

In this way  `LocalBroadcastManager` will be called only once.